How to convert XGBoost model to TensorflowLite?

How to convert Python XGBoost model to TensorflowLite?
I tried to convert it like described [here](https://github.com/joshuacwnewton/ONNX-to-TFLite/blob/master/onnx_to_tflite.ipynb) (first to ONNX format then to tf), but I got an error:
tf_rep.export_graph(tf_model_path)


line 349, in _onnx_node_to_tensorflow_op  *
        raise BackendIsNotSupposedToImplementIt("{} is not implemented.".format(

BackendIsNotSupposedToImplementIt: TreeEnsembleClassifier is not implemented.

Maybe there is another faster way to convert it?
